# what is the best html parser for java?

Tags: java, html, parsing

Assuming we have to use java, what is the best html parser that is flexible to parse lots of different html content, and also requires not a whole lot of code to do complex types of parses?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) for this. It has a very nice API with support for [jQuery like CSS selectors and non-verbose element iteration](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). To take a copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505/how-to-scan-a-website-or-page-for-info-and-bring-it-into-my-program/2835555#2835555) as an example, this prints your own question and the name of all answerers here:

```
URL url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121136");
Document document = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);

String question = document.select("#question .post-text").text();
System.out.println("Question: " + question);

Elements answerers = document.select("#answers .user-details a");
for (Element answerer : answerers) {
    System.out.println("Answerer: " + answerer.text());
}
```

An alternative would be [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp), but JSoup is more useful for webdevelopers who already have a good grasp on CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2):

The best would be the one that gets the job done right.

There is a opensource one called [tagsoup](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers/tagsoup), and also [jTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/)