# Regex for HTML with java.util.regex

Tags: java, html, regex

I need a regex for following html :

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    <p/>
  <p/><p/>    <p/>
</div>
```

This comes form a richtext field and obviously this is no meaningful content or means: empty.
I can not say in java: if (richTextConent == null || richTextContent.length == 0) because the richtext field contains something. Semantically the above content is empty so i thought of using a regex. I need to match this snippet with java.util.regex

If there is something meaningful in the snippet like:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> text<p/>
  <p/><p/>text    <p/>
</div>
```

than the regex should not match.

Comment: +1 for giving the bigger picture. I think a solution better than regexes will roll out.

Comment: is this something that is being done from the web, or a thin client or swing, or other?

Comment: Well, there is a richtexfield in a cms system which delivers its content as XML Markup. I need to know if the content is empty to surpress its rendering in a jsp template. As you can see from the example the content is not empty as this third party cms delivers empty tags and a div. So i thought regex would be fine to find out...

Comment: Does that mean you don't have control over the interface of the CMS?  If you did, I would maybe suggest using jQuery to get child nodes with text, otherwise I would go with @BalusC's answer

Comment: i have control over the interface. The problem ist that there seems to be bug. If i enter something in the editor and delete it again, the api of the cms still delivers this "empty" xml markup:-(
Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

```
String html1 = "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">    <p/>  <p/><p/>    <p/></div>";
String html2 = "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> text<p/>        <p/><p/>text    <p/>        </div>";

System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(html1).text().isEmpty()); // true
System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(html2).text().isEmpty()); // false
```

#### See also:

- [Should I parse (X)HTML with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
- [HTML parsers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)
- [Another Jsoup example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505/how-to-scan-a-website-or-page-for-info-and-bring-it-into-my-program/2835555#2835555)

Comment: Wow, i love Stackoverflow. It took only 4 minutes to get a qualified answer. I will give jsoup a try today. Thank you so far...