# How to get information from a webpage in Java?

Tags: java, html, file-io, jsoup

Does anyone know of a quick way that I can get information from a webpage in Java? For instance, if I'm looking at a page like this: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=10952317 and i want to extract the list of words beneath the heading "MeSH Terms", how would I go about doing so?

I have something that can read the source but it is full of HTML tags and such...

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "scan" a website (or page) for info, and bring it into my program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505/how-to-scan-a-website-or-page-for-info-and-bring-it-into-my-program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been mentioned on here countless times before have a look at [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), which is a HTML parsing library for Java.  Or write your own (not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Probably [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) is for you.