# Web Scraping with JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

I am new in scraping. I am trying, to scrape data from a site using JSOUP. I want to scrape data in from tags like `<div>`, `<span>`, `<p>` etc. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: Please tell us, what you have tried so far, SO is not the place for getting code magically.

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/

Comment: i have just made a new project and added a jsoup jar file and established a connection. i am actually new to this. i want to scrap data residing in different tags as i have shown above. plzzz help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505/how-to-scan-a-website-or-page-for-info-and-bring-it-into-my-program). A basic example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        String text = document.select("div").first().text();
        System.out.println(text);

        Elements links = document.select("a");
        for (Element link : links) {
            System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
        }
    }

}
```

This will first print the text of the first `div` on the page, and then print out all the url of all links (`a`) on the page.

---

To get div's with specific class, do `Elements elements = document.select("div.someclass")`

To get divs with a specific id, do `Elements elements = document.select("div#someclass")`

If you want to go through all the selected elements, do this:

```
for (Element e:elements) {
   System.out.println(e.text());
   //you can also do other things.
}
```

Comment: thanks JonasCz dear this was about first what about other div's and div with particular class names and ids

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas, If my answer helped you, it would be nice to _accept_ it by clicking the checkmark next to it :-)