# how to work with unusual html page content?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have successfully logged in http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us:8080/DWClient/Login.aspx
then I got page content. Page content was like view-sourse code in browser. OK!
Then I successfully got view2 http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us:8080/DWClient/View2.aspx it OK too!
Then I tryed to press "Well Files" and printed page content was

```
  1|#||4|97|updatePanel|DWC_DWMUP| 
   |0|hiddenField|__EVENTTARGET||0|hiddenField|__EVENTARGUMENT||1844|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE|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|564|hiddenField|__EVENTVALIDATION|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|0|asyncPostBackControlIDs|||0|postBackControlIDs|||228|updatePanelIDs||tDWC$DWMUP,,tDWC$DWNUP,,tW$Menu$Lo$UPMenu,,tW$Menu$Lo$UPMenuCmd,,tW$Se$SeC$SearchUpdatePanel,,tW$R$Rl$DWPanelResultLists,,tW$R$Rl$CommandAjaxHelpPanel,,tW$St$StC$StoreUpdatePanel,,tW$I$Ins$InfoUpdatePanel,,tW$Vi$Vp$CommandPanel,|0|childUpdatePanelIDs|||10|panelsToRefreshIDs||DWC$DWMUP,|2|asyncPostBackTimeout||90|35|formAction||View2.aspx?DWSubSession=4783&v=1589|36|pageTitle||DocuWare Public Web Client - Pubuser|62|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|if(typeof ($telerik)!='undefined'){$telerik.registerSkins();};|47|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Telerik.Web.UI.RadSplitter._preInitialize("S");|76|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Telerik.Web.UI.RadPane._preInitialize("P1", "S", "", "RS1", 0, 0, "False");|73|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Telerik.Web.UI.RadSplitBar._preInitialize("RS1", "S", "P1", "WBP", 1, 0);|76|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Telerik.Web.UI.RadPane._preInitialize("WBP", "S", "RS1", "", 2, 1, "True");|51|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Telerik.Web.UI.RadSplitter._preInitialize("Dummy");|83|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Telerik.Web.UI.RadPane._preInitialize("DummyPane", "Dummy", "", "", 0, 0, "True");|
```

WHY this code is different by view-sourse browser code???
I sent the same request as google chrome.
Ok, so then I tryed to press "search" and printed content was

```
  1|#||4|97|updatePanel|DWC_DWMUP| 
   |0|hiddenField|__EVENTTARGET||0|hiddenField|__EVENTARGUMENT||1844|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE|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|564|hiddenField|__EVENTVALIDATION|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|0|asyncPostBackControlIDs|||0|postBackControlIDs|||228|updatePanelIDs||tDWC$DWMUP,,tDWC$DWNUP,,tW$Menu$Lo$UPMenu,,tW$Menu$Lo$UPMenuCmd,,tW$Se$SeC$SearchUpdatePanel,,tW$R$Rl$DWPanelResultLists,,tW$R$Rl$CommandAjaxHelpPanel,,tW$St$StC$StoreUpdatePanel,,tW$I$Ins$InfoUpdatePanel,,tW$Vi$Vp$CommandPanel,|0|childUpdatePanelIDs|||10|panelsToRefreshIDs||DWC$DWMUP,|2|asyncPostBackTimeout||90|35|formAction||View2.aspx?DWSubSession=2849&v=1589|36|pageTitle||DocuWare Public Web Client - Pubuser|62|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|if(typeof ($telerik)!='undefined'){$telerik.registerSkins();};|47|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Telerik.Web.UI.RadSplitter._preInitialize("S");|76|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Telerik.Web.UI.RadPane._preInitialize("P1", "S", "", "RS1", 0, 0, "False");|73|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Telerik.Web.UI.RadSplitBar._preInitialize("RS1", "S", "P1", "WBP", 1, 0);|76|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Telerik.Web.UI.RadPane._preInitialize("WBP", "S", "RS1", "", 2, 1, "True");|51|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Telerik.Web.UI.RadSplitter._preInitialize("Dummy");|83|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Telerik.Web.UI.RadPane._preInitialize("DummyPane", "Dummy", "", "", 0, 0, "True");|
```

**So, what does it mean? And how to get data from this? Thank you a lot!**
Here my code

```
package com.company;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Parser {
    private String viewState;
    private String eventValidation;
    private String subSession;
    String url = "http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us:8080/DWClient/";
    List cookies;
    public void start() throws Exception{
        login();
        chooseWells();
        searchForm();
    }


    public void login() throws IOException {
        CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
        manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
        Connection connection = HttpConnection.connect(url + "Login.aspx");
        updateViewState(connection);
        try {
            Connection.Response res = connection
                    .data("DWC$DWMessages", "")
                    .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewState)
                    .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation)
                    .data("DWC_NotificationToolTip_ClientState", "")
                    .data("LoginWebPart$LoginTypes", "Guest")
                    .data("LoginWebPart$TextBoxUserName", "")
                    .data("LoginWebPart$TextBoxPassword", "")
                    .data("LoginWebPart$ButtonLogin", "Login")
                    .data("LoginWebPart_LanguageContextMenu_ClientState", "")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .timeout(6000)
                    .execute();
            CookieStore cookieJar = manager.getCookieStore();
            cookies = cookieJar.getCookies();
            Element element = res.parse().select("form").first();
            subSession = element.attr("action").substring(10);
            updateViewState(getView2());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private void updateViewState(Connection connection) throws IOException {
        Element element = connection.get().select("form").first();
        Element el = element.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE");
        viewState = el.attr("value");
        Element el1 = element.getElementById("__EVENTVALIDATION");
        eventValidation = el1.attr("value");
    }

    private void updateViewStateFromPartial(String html) throws IOException {
        String viewStateToken = "__VIEWSTATE|";
        int idx = html.indexOf(viewStateToken);
        int startIdx = idx + viewStateToken.length();
        int endIdx = html.indexOf("|", startIdx);
        viewState = html.substring(startIdx, endIdx);

        String eventValidationToken = "__EVENTVALIDATION|";
        idx = html.indexOf(eventValidationToken);
        startIdx = idx + eventValidationToken.length();
        endIdx = html.indexOf("|", startIdx);
        eventValidation = html.substring(startIdx, endIdx);
    }


    private Connection getView2() {
        url=url+"View2.aspx"+subSession;
        return Jsoup.connect(url);
    }

    public void chooseWells() throws IOException {
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .data("DWC%24SM", "W%24Menu%24Lo%24UPMenuCmd%7CW_Menu_Lo_ClickedMenuCmd")
                .data("__WPPS", "s")
                .data("__EVENTTARGET", "W_Menu_Lo_ClickedMenuCmd")
                .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
                .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewState)
                .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation)
                .data("DWC_FavouritesWindow_ClientState", "")
                .data("DWC_LinksWindow_ClientState", "")
                .data("DWC$24DWMessages", "")
                .data("DWC_NotificationToolTip_ClientState", "")
                .data("W_Menu_Lo_NormalMenu_ClientState", "")
                .data("W_Menu_Lo_LargeMenu_ClientState", "{\"logEntries\":[],\"selectedItemIndex\":\"4\"}\"")
                .data("W%24Menu%24Lo%24CPE_ClientState", "false")
                .data("W%24Menu%24Lo%24FavMenuCmd", "")
                .data("W%24Menu%24Lo%24ClickedMenuCmd", "1457348832725%2Cdb19b928-1c2d-4a0f-9963-95cc8d87bae9")
                .data("W%24Menu%24Lo%24ClientCommand", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24HiddenSearchUpdateField", "none")
                .data("W_Se_SeC_logicContextMenu_ClientState", "")
                .data("W%24St%24StC%24HiddenStoreUpdateField", "")
                .data("storeDialogClicked", "")
                .data("W%24R%24Rl%24CommandResultHiddenField", "")
                .data("W%24R%24Rl%24infoDlgMode", "Off")
                .data("W%24R%24Rl%24DblClickCommandHiddenField", "")
                .data("W%24R%24Rl%24CommandHiddenField", "")
                .data("W%24R%24Rl%24ClientCommands", "")
                .data("W_R_Rl_DWMenuCentral_ClientState", "")
                .data("W%24I%24Ins%24LastSelectedTab", "UserIndexes")
                .data("W%24I%24Ins%24infoDialogMode", "Off")
                .data("W%24I%24Ins%24HiddenInfoUpdateField", "")
                .data("W%24Vi%24Vp%24Commands", "")
                .data("W%24Vi%24Vp%24AnnotationTool", "")
                .data("P1_ClientState", "{\"_originalWidth\":\"\",\"_originalHeight\":\"400px\",\"_collapsedDirection\":1,\"_scrollLeft\":0,\"_scrollTop\":0,\"_expandedSize\":0,\"width\":2398,\"height\":561,\"collapsed\":false,\"contentUrl\":\"\",\"minWidth\":20,\"maxWidth\":10000,\"minHeight\":20,\"maxHeight\":10000,\"locked\":false}")
                .data("RS1_ClientState", "")
                .data("DummyPane_ClientState", "{\"_originalWidth\":\"398px\",\"_originalHeight\":\"\",\"_collapsedDirection\":1,\"_scrollLeft\":0,\"_scrollTop\":0,\"_expandedSize\":0,\"width\":2398,\"height\":160,\"collapsed\":false,\"contentUrl\":\"\",\"minWidth\":20,\"maxWidth\":10000,\"minHeight\":33,\"maxHeight\":10000,\"locked\":false}")
                .data("Dummy_ClientState", "")
                .data("WBP_ClientState", "{\"_originalWidth\":\"\",\"_originalHeight\":\"\",\"_collapsedDirection\":1,\"_scrollLeft\":0,\"_scrollTop\":0,\"_expandedSize\":160,\"width\":2398,\"height\":0,\"collapsed\":true,\"contentUrl\":\"\",\"minWidth\":20,\"maxWidth\":10000,\"minHeight\":33,\"maxHeight\":10000,\"locked\":true}")
                .data("S_ClientState", "")
                .data("__ASYNCPOST", "true")
                .header("DWASPSession", String.valueOf(cookies.get(2)).substring(10))
                .header("DWSubSession", subSession.substring(14,18))
                .header("X-MicrosoftAjax", "Delta=true")
                .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                .timeout(5000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
        Element element = response.parse().select("html").first();
        System.out.println( element);
        updateViewStateFromPartial(element.text());
    }

    public void searchForm() throws IOException {
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .data("DWC$24SM", "W%24Se%24SeC%24SearchUpdatePanel%7CW%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24btnCtrl")
                .data("__WPPS", "s")

                .data("DWC_FavouritesWindow_ClientState", "")
                .data("DWC_LinksWindow_ClientState", "")
                .data("DWC$24DWMessages", "")
                .data("DWC_NotificationToolTip_ClientState", "")
                .data("W_Menu_Lo_NormalMenu_ClientState", "")
                .data("W_Menu_Lo_LargeMenu_ClientState", "{\"logEntries\":[],\"selectedItemIndex\":\"4\"}\"")//
                .data("W%24Menu%24Lo%24CPE_ClientState", "false")
                .data("W%24Menu%24Lo%24FavMenuCmd", "")
                .data("W%24Menu%24Lo%24ClickedMenuCmd", "")
                .data("W%24Menu%24Lo%24ClientCommand", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24HiddenSearchUpdateField", "none")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%24P", "0")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%24Co", "0")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%24Ma", "0")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%24Cl", "0")
                .data("W_Se_SeC_P_1_1CC_ssd_slm_ClientState", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F0%24T", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F1%24T", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F2%24T", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F3%24T", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F4%24T", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F5%24T", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F6%24T", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F7%24T", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F8%24T", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F9%24T", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F10%24D1", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F10%24D2", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F11%24T", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F12%24D1", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24IF%24F12%24D2", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24SearchMod", "And")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24SC", "")
                .data("W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%24CPE_ClientState", "false")
                .data("W_Se_SeC_logicContextMenu_ClientState", "")
                .data("W%24St%24StC%24HiddenStoreUpdateField", "")
                .data("storeDialogClicked", "")
                .data("W%24R%24Rl%24CommandResultHiddenField", "")
                .data("W%24R%24Rl%24infoDlgMode", "Off")
                .data("W%24R%24Rl%24DblClickCommandHiddenField", "")
                .data("W%24R%24Rl%24CommandHiddenField", "")
                .data("W%24R%24Rl%24ClientCommands", "")
                .data("W_R_Rl_DWMenuCentral_ClientState", "")
                .data("W%24I%24Ins%24LastSelectedTab", "UserIndexes")
                .data("W%24I%24Ins%24infoDialogMode", "Off")
                .data("W%24I%24Ins%24HiddenInfoUpdateField", "")
                .data("W%24Vi%24Vp%24Commands", "")
                .data("W%24Vi%24Vp%24AnnotationTool", "")
                .data("P1_ClientState", "{\"_originalWidth\":\"\",\"_originalHeight\":\"400px\",\"_collapsedDirection\":1,\"_scrollLeft\":0,\"_scrollTop\":0,\"_expandedSize\":0,\"width\":2398,\"height\":561,\"collapsed\":false,\"contentUrl\":\"\",\"minWidth\":20,\"maxWidth\":10000,\"minHeight\":20,\"maxHeight\":10000,\"locked\":false}")
                .data("RS1_ClientState", "")
                .data("DummyPane_ClientState", "{\"_originalWidth\":\"398px\",\"_originalHeight\":\"\",\"_collapsedDirection\":1,\"_scrollLeft\":0,\"_scrollTop\":0,\"_expandedSize\":0,\"width\":2398,\"height\":160,\"collapsed\":false,\"contentUrl\":\"\",\"minWidth\":20,\"maxWidth\":10000,\"minHeight\":33,\"maxHeight\":10000,\"locked\":false}")
                .data("Dummy_ClientState", "")
                .data("WBP_ClientState", "{\"_originalWidth\":\"\",\"_originalHeight\":\"\",\"_collapsedDirection\":1,\"_scrollLeft\":0,\"_scrollTop\":0,\"_expandedSize\":160,\"width\":2398,\"height\":0,\"collapsed\":true,\"contentUrl\":\"\",\"minWidth\":20,\"maxWidth\":10000,\"minHeight\":33,\"maxHeight\":10000,\"locked\":true}")
                .data("S_ClientState", "")
                .data("__ASYNCPOST", "true")
                .data("__EVENTTARGET", "W%24Se%24SeC%24P%241%241CC%24ssd%24btnCtrl")
                .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
                .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewState)
                .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation)
                .data("__ASYNCPOST", "true")


                .header("DWASPSession", String.valueOf(cookies.get(2)).substring(10))
                .header("DWSubSession", subSession.substring(14,18))
                .header("X-MicrosoftAjax", "Delta=true")
                .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36")
                .timeout(10000)
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();

        System.out.println(response.parse().select("html"));
        getTabularResults(response.parse().select("html").toString());

    }

    private List<DocMetaData> getTabularResults(String raw){
        List<DocMetaData> docs=new ArrayList<>();
        String html=getTabularHtml(raw);
        Document document=Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element table=document.getElementById("W_R_Rl_P_1_1CC_ctl01_ctl00");
        for (Element td: table.select("tbody/tr")
             ) {
            List<Element> columns=td.select("td");
            DocMetaData doc=new DocMetaData();
            doc.setLeastName(String.valueOf(columns.get(1)));
            docs.add(doc);
        }
        return docs;

    }
    private String getTabularHtml(String raw){
        String startToken="W_R_Rl_DWPanelResultLists|";
        int startIdx=raw.indexOf(startToken)+startToken.length();
        int endIdx=raw.indexOf("|0|",startIdx);
        String result=raw.substring(startIdx,endIdx);
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will never get a 1:1 match for how browsers interpret HTML. It's all a best-effort, and browsers are insanely complicated in order to be somewhat compatible with several decades worth of broken HTML :)

Even if you manage to mimic Chrome's behavior, it will probably not match Firefox, Opera or even the next version of Chrome.

For your second question (it's usually best to only ask one) just use Jsoup and try to extract the things you need - don't worry too much about what Chrome says. Maybe the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2835505/98057) are helpful?

Comment: eh, no. Look at the printed content. There are no elements, no tags. Just text, without information I need( Nevertheless thank you. Maybe something else?

Comment: sorry. there are <html><head></head><body>"printed text"</body></html>

Comment: Can you try to create a minimal working example of your problem? Your code (and the off-SO sample html) is a bit much to digest at the moment. At least for me :)

Comment: mm...it's a problem) The third step of the implementation of my program(method searchForm()) does not return the expected result. Just follow the link http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us:8080/DWClient/Login.aspx   ->Login->Well Files->Search. 
Аnd you will see a table with the data that I need to get. If that's not too much trouble for you. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't create minimal working example. Only this.