# Jsoup not installed on macbook pro? Class Test has compile errors jsoup

Tags: java, macos, jsoup

So I'm writting a code I got from a post here and it uses jsoup.. I'm also USING A MACBOOK PRO version 10.11.3 and my java is up to date.

The code is

```
package com.stackoverflow.q2835505;

import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    String question = document.select("#question .post-text").text();
    System.out.println("Question: " + question);

    Elements answerers = document.select("#answers .user-details a");
    for (Element answerer : answerers) {
        System.out.println("Answerer: " + answerer.text());
    }
}

}
```

THE PROBLEM I'm having is that I get the compile errors:

```
Jack-MacBook-Pro:desktop iModelEx$ javac Test.java
Test.java:3: error: package org.jsoup does not exist
import org.jsoup.*;
^
Test.java:4: error: package org.jsoup.nodes does not exist
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
^
Test.java:5: error: package org.jsoup.select does not exist
import org.jsoup.select.*;
^
Test.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        ^
  symbol:   class Document
  location: class Test
Test.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                        ^
  symbol:   variable Jsoup
  location: class Test
Test.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        Elements answerers = document.select("#answers .user-details a");
        ^
  symbol:   class Elements
  location: class Test
Test.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        for (Element answerer : answerers) {
             ^
  symbol:   class Element
  location: class Test
7 errors
```

So that being said, I downloaded jsoup-1.10.1.jar but I don't know if I should leave it on the desktop or put it into a folder? Or open it somehow? What should I do? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: This is a specific problem with Jsoup and not my code, since all the errors point to jsoup files which apparently aren't implemented properly in my java library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Comment: Nope, this is jsoup specific, my java works fine its just this one library :(

Comment: No please read above link, it means your jsoup jar is not available in classpath!

Comment: Oh really! Ok I will read it :D

Comment: Ok still don't get it. I'm doing everything right. The only problem is that my import jsoup is not importing the files. Can someone tell me what I can do to fix this? I have spent the past 2 hours tryign to figure this out

Answer (score 1):

You have to download [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download).

After downloading jsoup go to your project properties->java build path->libraries->add external jar

And then find your jsoup.jar that you just downloaded.

Comment: Ok but how do I access project properties? Like I don't even know where to click this is java for beginners for me

Comment: There are two ways to do that.

Comment: On the top of your screen there is a tab saying project, and under that tab there is a project properties. Also if you right click your project on the left side of your screen it will show your project properties. I can send you a screenshot if you are still having problems.

Comment: Hmm I think I'm forgetting to tell you I'm coding in a txt file. So I literary have no project button anywhere on my screen. I'm on a macbook pro

Comment: I would recommend you to download eclipse.

Comment: Or alternative to Eclipse, NetBeans or IntelliJ IDEs.