# How to get the last 5 articles from a website with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm working currently on a java desktop app for a company and they ask me, to extract the 5 last articles from a web page and and to display them in the app. To do this I need a html parser of course and I thought directly about JSoup. But my problem is how do i do it exactly? I found one easy example from this question: [Example: How to “scan” a website (or page) for info, and bring it into my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505/how-to-scan-a-website-or-page-for-info-and-bring-it-into-my-program)

with this code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.q2835505;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup; 
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        String question = document.select("#question .post-text").text();
        System.out.println("Question: " + question);

        Elements answerers = document.select("#answers .user-details a");
        for (Element answerer : answerers) {
            System.out.println("Answerer: " + answerer.text());
        }
    }

}
```

this code was written by BalusC and i understand it, but how do i do it when the links are not fixed, which is the case in most newspaper for example. For the sake of simplicity, how would i go to extract for example the 5 last articles from this news page: [News](https://globalnews.ca/world/)?
I can't use a rss feed as my boss wants the complete articles to be displayed.

Comment: can u try with [hacker news](https://news.ycombinator.com/) link? by the way what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Scroll to the link that says [RSS](https://globalnews.ca/pages/feeds/) and use [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS). In fact, I should post this as **the answer**. Oh, and [here](https://globalnews.ca/world/feed/) is the world feed.

Comment: Thank you Gauthaman and Elliot, but i already thought about this and my boss don't want a rss feed, he wants all 5 articles complete, not as a preview, like it's displayed in rss feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to download the main page:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://globalnews.ca/world/").get();
```

Then you select links you are interested in for example with [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
You select all `a` tags that contains `href` with text `globalnews` and are nested in `h3` tag with class `story-h`. Urls are in `href` attribute of `a` tag.

```
    for(Element e: doc.select("h3.story-h > a[href*=globalnews]")) {
        System.out.println(e.attr("href"));
    }
```

Then the resulting urls you can process as you wish. You can download content of the first five of then using syntax from the first line etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what i was looking for Luk!!