# Problem to get complete HTML code from an URL

Tags: java, android

When I try to get the HTML source from this url : https://www.weatherlink.com/embeddablePage/show/44a2d6b116484f5a8013ffad079046b9/slim

If I request the source code to Chrome Navigator, I see :

```
< body class="embeddable-page-body">
< !-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
< noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NLLVC3L" height="0" width="0" "display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>

< div class="embeddable-page-container">
< /div>
```

If I see Google inspector, I can read :

```
< div class="embeddable-page-container">
< div>
< div class="embeddable-page embeddable-page-slim">
< div class="container-fluid">
::before
< div class="row embeddable-page-header" style="height: 54px;">
::before
< span> Plage Thalès < /span>
< br>
< span class="conditions" id="conditionsUpdated" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Last successful refresh at 11:37 Jul 08,2023"> Conditions as of: 11:37 Saturday, Jul 08,2023 < /span>
::after
< /div>
< /div>
```

How to get the information inside the "embeddable-page-container" DIV and so on ? Or a more precise question : how to get the date of the last successful refresh, which is in '<span class="conditions" ...' inside "embeddable-page-container", inside "embeddable-page embeddable-page-slim", inside "container-fluid", inside "row embeddable-page-header slim-embeddable-page-header" ?

I tried with URLConnection and a BufferReader.
I tried with Ion.
I tied with jsoup.

In all cases, the result was an empty < div class="embeddable-page-container"> :

Comment: Sorry, a part of the copy/paste was interpreted. Here is what I received :<div class="embeddable-page-container">
                                                                                                    </div>

Comment: You need an HTML parser to build the DOM where you can search for HTML elements. On Java on common that still works even if the page is not 100% compliant to the HTML spec is https://jsoup.org See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835555/150978

Comment: I tried '''Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();" but when I try to search '''Elements elements = body.select(".embeddable-page-slim");''' Elements is still empty

Comment: `embeddable-page-slim` is different from `embeddable-page-body` in your question, is this a typo? Print the HTML code retrieved by Jsoup to make sure you really get the same HTML file and the element you search is really present.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: First message updated.